# Having issues with value of 08 Using SET /a in a windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a bunch of batch files that use set /a to fill out variables for month, day, year, etc.

Example:

```
Set/a Year = %date:~10,4%
Set/a Month = %date:~4,2%
Set/a Day = %date:~7,2%
```

Any time the value of the month or day is 08, the expression fails, but it works fine on other days/months, so there must be something special about how 08 is being evaluated, can anyone tell me why?

Example:

```
C:\>Set/a Month = %date:~4,2%
Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17),
hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021).
```

I didn't originally write these files, but do maintain them, and SET seems to work fine without using the /a, so that solves my immediate problem, but would still like to understand why 08 is an issue when 07, 06, etc. aren't.

Comment: I know, this is not your question, but if you really need the month to do math with it: `set /a month=1%date:~4,2%-100`, which will give you `8` for August. (Note that the `4` depends on the current local settings and therefore `%date:~4,2%` might give something unexpected. On my computer, I'd have to use %date:~3,2%`)

Answer (score 2):

Octal uses only 0-7, 8 and 9 are not numbers in it. 08 is an octal literal, but an invalid one (8 in octal is 011), thus the error. Drop the leading 0.

It gets these values from your locale settings, so I know "drop the 0" is kinda useless advice. The reason it's working without the /a is because of the data type I'd say (and type conversion):

```
set [<variable>=[<string>]]
set /a <variable>=<expression>
```

In the first syntax, the variable is set to a string, in your case '08', which is converted to a number (implicitly, because date expects a number) by dropping the leading 0 (or 0s), so it's being interpreted as the number 8.

When 08 is an expression instead, as in the 2nd syntax, it is interpreted as a numeric literal first, in this case octal, and 08 is invalid.

Comment: ah, it hadn't occurred to me that the expression would evaluate using octal instead of converting it to decimal. makes sense now why not using the /a command works, since the 'older' method of evaluating expressions would still work.

Comment: I suppose not having `/a` entirely depends if you actually have to do the arithmetic expression or not.  Have you done some unit testing on the script?  *You should be able to test 31 days easily enough.*

Comment: It's using octal because you used 08. In the error description, the end says "or octal (021)". When you say 08, that is an (invalid) octal literal. If it was just 8 it would be decimal, and likely work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it with some math.

```
set /a month=1%date:~4,2% - 100
```

This prefix the number with a `1`, all two digit month will become a valid number over one hundred.
Then it's only necessary to subtract 100.

```
08 -> 180
12 -> 112
```